# General Space Markov Chains: Petite sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

In a general state space $X$  markov chain $\Phi$  we define a petite set $C\subset X$ if the following property holds for any measurable $B\subset X$ for a given $x\in C$

$$K_a(x,B)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^{n}(x,B)a(n)\ge \nu(B)$$

where $P^n(x,B)$ is the transition probability from x to B in n steps and $a(n)$ is a sampling distribution and $\nu$ is a non-trivial set measure. $a(n)$ can be thought of as the proportion of times one transitions using $P^n(x,C)$. We define the property $B\overset{a}{\rightsquigarrow}C$ if

$$\underset{x\in B}{\text{inf}}K_a(x,C)>\delta>0$$

Now I am looking at a proof that purports to say that

$$\underset{x\in B}{\text{sup}}P_x(\sigma_C\ge n)< \frac{1}{2}$$

for some large enough n implies that $B\overset{a}{\rightsquigarrow}C$, where

$$\sigma_C=\text{inf}\{n\ge 0, \Phi_n\in C\}.$$

The consideration of the petite set comes into play when we let $C$ be a petite set and $B\overset{a}{\rightsquigarrow}C$ implies $B$ is a petite set.  I have tried constructing a sampling distribution $a(n)$ using this assumption but am having trouble understanding the importance of $\frac{1}{2}$ and the implication. Any hint or guidance would be much appreciated.

Further Attempt:

After careful thought this is what I came up with.

Since $P_x(\sigma_c\ge N)<\frac{1}{2}$  for an $N$ then I know that

$$P_x(\sigma_C<N) > \frac{1}{2}$$.

Since $P_x(\sigma_C<N)=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P_x(\sigma_C=k)\le \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P^k(x,C)$

This implies that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P^k(x,C)>\frac{1}{2}, \text{ for any } x\in B$$

Then if I define the uniform sampling distribution

$a(k)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{N-1}  &  1\le k \le N-1\\
0   &  k\ge N\\
\end{cases}$

then I get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P^k(x,C)a(k)>\frac{1}{2(N-1)}, \text{ for any } x\in B$$

since $\frac{1}{2(N-1)}>0$  then

$$\underset{x\in C_V(l)}{\text{inf}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P^k(x,C)a(k)>\frac{1}{2(N-1)}>0$$  and get

$$B\overset{a}{\rightsquigarrow}C$$ as needed. Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm a bit confused what $a(n)$ is. Is it a distribution on the nonnegative integers that you are using as weights to define $K_a$? Also, the notion of petiteness seems irrelevant to the rest of the question.

Comment: @Ian I have updated my post to include some of your questions. The book is trying to show that if we define $V_C(x)=1+E_x[\sigma_C]$ that this function is bounded off petite sets that is $C_V(l)=\{x\in X: V_x\le l \}$ is a petite set one way is to show  that $C_V(l)\overset{a}{\rightsquigarrow} C$

Comment: @Ian I have updated my question with an attempt. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is Lemma 9.4.7 from [Markov Chains](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-97704-1):

$$
\inf_{x \in B} \mathbb{P}_x(\sigma_C \le n) > 0 \iff \inf_{x \in B}K_{\gamma_n}(x, C) > 0.
$$

Here $\gamma_n$ is uniform on $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ so it's more specific than what you have.

When you assume $\underset{x\in B}{\text{sup}}P_x(\sigma_C\ge n)< \frac{1}{2}$ then

$$
\inf_{x \in B} \mathbb{P}_x(\sigma_C \le n)
= 1 - \sup_{x \in B}\mathbb{P}_x(\sigma_C > n) > 1/2 
$$
and you're done.

Their proof to the lemma is simply the statement that both sides are equivalent to a third condition: there exists a positive $\delta$ such that, for all $x \in B$ there exists $r(x) \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ such that $P^{r(x)}(x, C) \ge \delta / n$.